# Get UpTime from powershell into a usable way, but can't get it to work

Tags: powershell, time, return-value, selection

I've been making this program where i need to send a command to powershell and in return it gives me the sys UpTime (minutes work better but not mandatory)

As i'm still not used to using powershell, i'm having a lot of problems in getting this intel.

This is what i tryed:

```
    (get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
```

Gives me the uptime, but i still have no idea how to work with that, so i still need to somehow add something like:

```
    | Select-String -Pattern "TotalMinutes"
```

But then i need (somehow) to make that powershell gives me that time as return so i can work with it.
maybe to clipboard?

```
    | clip
```

But if i add all those up, none will work.
Putting in the clipboard is just a way i made to get this info, others might also work.
I'm still very new to this, sorry if i hurt your intellect with stupid questions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to use Select-Object: `(get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime | Select-Object TotalMinutes` and if you want just the value: `((get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime).TotalMinutes | Clip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By subtracting two `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) instances, you get a `[timespan]` ([`System.TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan)) instance, which you can store in a variable:

```
$timeSpanSinceBoot = (Get-Date) - (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
```

You can then access its properties as needed, such as `.TotalMinutes`:

```
$timeSpanSinceBoot.TotalMinutes
```

To examine the members of the time-span value's type, use the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Member) cmdlet:

```
$timeSpanSinceBoot | Get-Member # lists properties and methods
```